# Removing a specific trade from a villager (minecraft 1.16)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm trying to make it so that when a villager runs out of stock of a specific trade, it removes that trade from the villager.

I'm stuck at the part where I remove the trade.
So far I can only wipe the villager's trades or add a new trade, but not remove a specific trade.

I've tried using

```
/data modify with the path : Offers.Recipes[{buy:{id:”minecraft:stone”},sell:{id:”minecraft stone”}}]
```

I've also tried it with the Count tag, but it does not work either.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you please specify what you have tried?

Comment: ive tried /data modify entity @e[type=“minecraft:villager”] Offers.Recipes[trade] insert 1 value newtrade                    
Ive also tried this for append set merge and prepend and am usure if my target path is sufficent for what i am trying to do.

Comment: im trying to make a datapack that adds a quest system to minecraft. the quests are started by quest items sold by villagers. i want the quests trades to be removed when they run out of stock but still keep the original trades that the villagers have. this way i can refresh the quests trades after a certain amount of time.

Comment: It would be better if you put that content from the comment into your post by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `/data modify`, use `/data remove`.

```
/data remove @e[type=villager,name="TheVillagerToActUpon",limit=1] Offers.Recipes[{buy:{id:"minecraft:stone"},sell:{id:"minecraft:stone"},Uses:5}]
```

Replace the `5` in `Uses:5` to say how many times the trade can be used. Put the command in a repeating command block.

Comment: Thanks! it took a bit of tinkering but i was able to remove a trade using this!